# Last word/sentence on an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, alphabetical

I have an assignment, it looks pretty easy however I cannot figure it out how to solve it.

It says:

- a) Ask the user: How many words/sentences do you want to write (at
  least 5) ? (Use ***while*** loop)
- b) Use ***for*** loop to make the user write the words/sentences
- c) After the user's written the words/sentences, output which
  word/sentence comes last alphabetically (using ***.compareTo()*** method )

This is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LastString {
public static void main (String [] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

final short MIN_NUM = 2;
int num = 0;
int count = 0;
String [] sentence = new String [0];
String last = "";

while (num < MIN_NUM){
  System.out.println("How many words/sentences do you want to put? " + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t --- at least " + MIN_NUM);
  num = input.nextInt();
  sentence = new String [num];
}


for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++ ) {
  System.out.println("\nWrite a word/sentence" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t --- (Time: " + (i+1) + " )");
  sentence [i] = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("The word/sentence is:  " + sentence[i]);
}

int i = 0;
int max;

for (i=0;i<num-1 ;i++ ) {
  if(sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i+1]) > 0){
    last = sentence[i];
    count ++;
  }else if (sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i+1]) < 0) {
      last = sentence[i+1];
      count++;
  }
}

System.out.println("\n\n------------" +
                  "\nLast word/sentence is: " + last);



System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentence));

}

}
```

I compiles and runs. I have two problems:

1. nextLine >>> it is skiping the first Sentence
2. I don't know how to make the algorithm to calculate which word/sentence has the biggest value or, using the compareTo() method which word/sentence has the value > 0 compared to each and every other value on the array.

Thank you.

Comment: What determining factor can be applied to a "sentence" to sort it alphabetically?

Comment: I do not understand the question. If you mean uppercase lower case, it doesn't matter. A word or a sentence does it.

Comment: Answer to Q 1 : `num = input.nextInt();` takes a number as the input but doesn't also consume the new-line, and hence the `nextLine` consumes the empty new line ... you could use `input.nextLine` also to get the first number instead of `num = input.nextInt();`by reading a line, then parsing the int value as `num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`

Comment: Did you already tried to write a algorithm to find the max value in an array ? It is the same idea here but with compareTo

Comment: I have tried it multiple times, the best I've come up is this one here at line: I don't know, it works for 2 word/s sentences, other wise it doesn't, it only compare the two last entries.

 for (i=0;i<num-1 ;i++ ) {
  if(sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i+1]) > 0){
    last = sentence[i]; I don't know, it works for 2 word/s sentences, other wise it doesn't, it only compare the two last entries.
    count ++;
  }else if (sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i+1]) < 0) {
      last = sentence[i+1];
      count++;
  }
}

Comment: No, I don't mean uppercase or lowercase.  I more so am interested in how your professor would sort a sentence alphabetically.  If you use standard sort mechanisms, a very short sentence that is full of `z`s will be sorted before a longer sentence full of `a`s.  For some reason, this seems incorrect to me.

Comment: Hint for second one - put the first word in a variable then compare other words with it, updating the variable if a "better" word is found.

Comment: @Exception_al thank you very much, It solved it.

Comment: @CraigR8806 , well the only method that we learned to compare the words/sentences is the 
    .compareTo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1 : `num = input.nextInt();` takes a number as the input but doesn't also consume the new-line, and hence the `nextLine` consumes the empty new line ... you could use `input.nextLine` also to get the first number instead of `num = input.nextInt();` by reading a line, then parsing the int value as `num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`

Answer to Q2 :

You re-set the value of `last` everytime but you don't compare the value of the next biggest candidate with the `last` before re-assigning last ...

for example, look at the following :

```
for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
    String thisLast = "";
    if (sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i + 1]) > 0) {
        thisLast = sentence[i];
        count++;
    } else if (sentence[i].compareTo(sentence[i + 1]) < 0) {
        thisLast = sentence[i + 1];
        count++;
    }

    if (thisLast.compareTo(last) > 0)
        last = thisLast;

}
```

Comment: Wow! That simple! Thank you very much sir. It works. Gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

it will solve your problem....

```
    int count = 0;
    String [] sentence = new String[6];
    String last = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++ ) {
      System.out.println("\nWrite a word/sentence" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ---        (Time: " + (i+1) + " )");
      sentence [i] = input.nextLine();
      count++;
      if(count >= 2){
          if(sentence[i].compareTo(last) > 0){
              last = sentence [i] ;
          }
      }else{
          last = sentence [i];
      }
      System.out.println("The word/sentence is:  " + sentence[i]);
```

}